# Create Unique ID for CSS with reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create an image slider with reactJS. (no webpack, no jsx). I started with different elements, one to take any number of images in, then radio buttons that when clicked on, display the other image. (I'm basically trying to replicate this: https://codepen.io/alehl/pen/wjJLJz, but with reactJS).

These are the elements and how I'm looping to pass in the images & render them + the a radio button for each image.

```
   const sliders = image_urls.map((current_image =>
    React.createElement("z", { type: "radio", name: "slider", id: "slide" })
  ));

  const sliders2 = image_urls.map((current_image =>
    React.createElement("label", { "for": "slide", className: "radio_button" })
  ));

  const final_images = image_urls.map((current_image =>
      React.createElement(
        "img",
        { src: current_image }
      )
  ));
```

The problem is... that the ids in the CSS are unique for each slide:

```
#slide1:checked ~ #slides article:nth-child(1) .info,
#slide2:checked ~ #slides article:nth-child(2) .info,
#slide3:checked ~ #slides article:nth-child(3) .info,
#slide4:checked ~ #slides article:nth-child(4) .info,
#slide5:checked ~ #slides article:nth-child(5) .info {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 1s ease-out 0.6s;
}
```

My question is: Is there a way to loop through the id & increment by 1 to form the needed unique id for each slide? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: in pure css there are no loops but sass or less offers loops `@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  #slide#{$i} {
    ..css
  }
}`

Comment: Second arg in map functions is index... `.map(( (current_image, index) =>`